# Highgui.write() not working correctly

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision

I have two images - `rectangle.jpg` and `replica.jpg` (Blank image) both of size 307x185 and color image.

I want to copy content of `rectangle.jpg` to `replica.jpg`

For which my opencv code in android is :

```
    String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/idag/rectangle.jpg;
    Mat m=Highgui.imread(path,1);               
    String path1=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/idag/replica.jpg";
    Highgui.imwrite(path1, m);
```

Both the images are in location  `/sdcard/idag`.
Code is not giving any error in running on mobile after installing it on `Android 2.3.3 API 10` but image is also "not copied" to desired blank image.

Where am I doing mistake ?

Comment: Hey guys, i got the solution. It was a simple mistake, I forgot to add user permission of "WriteExternalStorage". After adding it solved the problem.